# Fundamental group of topological product space

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, fundamental-groups

This question here: [What would the fundamental group of disjoint union look like?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590083/what-would-the-fundamental-group-of-disjoint-union-look-like) partly (or perhaps totally) addresses my issue, but I need anyway an explicit answer.

**Problem:** Let $U, V, W$ be connected Lie groups, so that, at topological level, 
$U$ is homeomorphic to the product $V \times W$. Let $\pi_1 (U), \pi_1 (V), \pi_1 (W)$ be their fundamental groups. Is it true that: $\pi_1 (U) = \pi_1 (V) \times \pi_1 (W)$? If yes, how is it proved, if no, what other topological restrictions on the underlying manifolds are needed to make it true?

Comment: The disjoint union of two spaces is never connected.

Comment: Ok, then the quoted question doesn't help. Then my question remains. I have in mind that the topological manifold of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is homemorphic to the product of the manifolds of $\text{SU}(2)$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  See [Hatcher](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html) Proposition 1.12.

For manifolds, connected is equivalent to path-connected, so the proposition applies.

Comment: Thank you. Spot on. I somehow "felt" there was a general result like this.